# Java Scanner issues (JFrame)

Tags: java, image, file, jframe, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use a scanner to edit the level of my tower defense game. However it will not update the level (the tile images) to that of the custom file (0 is grass 1 is stone -1 is nothing, etc.). I have found the error but how do i fix it, what do i need to add/change to get rid of this?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Levels.loadLevels(Levels.java:11)
    at Window.define(Window.java:28)
    at Window.paintComponent(Window.java:44)
```

line 11: `for(int y=0;y<Window.room.block.length;y++) {`
line 28: `levels.loadLevels(new File("levels/level1.level"));`
line 44: `define();`

This is the scanner file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Levels {
    public void loadLevels(File loadPath) {
        try {
            Scanner loadLevelsScanner = new Scanner(loadPath);

            while(loadLevelsScanner.hasNext()) {

                for(int y=0;y<Window.room.block.length;y++) {
                    for(int x=0;x<Window.room.block[0].length;x++) {
                        Window.room.block[y][x].groundID = loadLevelsScanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                for(int y=0;y<Window.room.block.length;y++) {
                    for(int x=0;x<Window.room.block[0].length;x++) {
                        Window.room.block[y][x].airID = loadLevelsScanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }    
            }               
            loadLevelsScanner.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {              
        }
    }
}
```

this is the window file:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Window extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public Thread thread = new Thread(this);        
    public static Image[] tileset_ground = new Image[100];
    public static Image[] tileset_air = new Image[100];     
    public static int myWidth, myHeight;        
    public static boolean isFirst = true;       
    public static Room room;
    public static Levels levels;

    public Window() {
        thread.start();
    }

    public void define() {
        room = new Room();
        levels = new Levels();          
        levels.loadLevels(new File("levels/level1.level"));

        for(int i=0;i<tileset_ground.length; i++) {
            tileset_ground[i] = new ImageIcon("resources/tileset_ground.png").getImage();
            tileset_ground[i] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(tileset_ground[i].getSource(), new CropImageFilter(0, 32 * i, 32, 32)));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<tileset_air.length; i++) {
            tileset_air[i] = new ImageIcon("resources/tileset_air.png").getImage();
            tileset_air[i] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(tileset_air[i].getSource(), new CropImageFilter(0, 32 * i, 32, 32)));
        }    
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(isFirst) {
            define();               
            isFirst = false;
        }           
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());         
        room.draw(g);
    }

    public void run() { 
        while(true) {               
            if(!isFirst) {
                room.physic();
            }               
            repaint();              
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(Exception e) {
            }               
        }           
    }       
}
```

This is the room file:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Room {
    public int worldWidth = 40;
    public int worldHeight = 20;
    public int blockSize = 32;

    public Block[][] block;

    public Room () { }
    public void define () { }    
    public void physic () { }   

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        block = new Block[worldHeight][worldWidth];         

        for(int y=0;y<block.length;y++) {
            for(int x=0;x<block[0].length;x++) {
                block[y][x] = new Block(x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize, Value.groundGrass, Value.airAir);
                block[y][x].draw(g);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

this is the block file:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Block extends Rectangle {
    public int groundID;
    public int airID;

    public Block(int x, int y, int width, int height, int groundID, int airID) {
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        this.groundID = groundID;
        this.airID = airID;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(Window.tileset_ground[groundID], x, y, width, height, null);

        if(airID != Value.airAir) {
            g.drawImage(Window.tileset_air[airID], x, y, width, height, null);
        }           
    }       
}
```

And lastly this is the custom file the scanner is supposed to read:

```
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

sorry for the stupid question, i'm a beginner.

Comment: *"What frustrates me the most is that there are no errors"* `} catch(Exception e) {

        }`  Change that (and every similar statement) to `catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        }` (..or alternately remain in the dark).

Comment: How do you know that there is no error since you swallow your exceptions: `catch (Exception e) {}`. Obviously, if you ignore any exception that might be thrown, you'll get the impression that there is no error. But this impression has a good chance of not being the reality.

Comment: *"Sorry for the long post"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `new ImageIcon("resources/tileset_ground.png")`   That reminds me.  In all those methods/constructors that are presuming a `String` to represent a `File` path, it probably needs an `URL` instead.  Those type of 'embedded resources' will not be accessible at run-time as `File` objects.

Comment: int y=0; can't throw a NPE, nor y++. So Window.room.block, or Window.room or Window is null.

Comment: so how can i go about fixing this? sorry i'm a beginner.

Comment: Never ever catch the generic Exception. Always catch specific ones, which you expect - else you'll catch unexpected Exceptions. And nearly always: React on Exceptions. Some exceptions might not mind you - make a short loginfo then. At least make a comment in the source code, where you explain why you ignore it, to prevent you ignoring them for being lazy. Maybe Window.define () isn't called, and Room is uninitialized?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is called, how can i know for sure? Meaning, how can i check?

Comment: Note: To inform me, you have to put @user unknown in front of your comment, as long as you don't comment on my question/answer. Else, I will not mention, that you made an answer/new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty solution is, to test for Window.room not to be null, as well as .block:

```
        Scanner loadLevelsScanner = new Scanner (loadPath);
        if ((Window.room != null) && 
            (Window.room.block != null)) {
            // ... block until catch block 
        }
```

A simple Testapp I've written works so far, if done so.

But you need to understand what "static" is, and why and how to use it. A common beginner mistake is, to instert "static" keywords just to make the compiler silent.

Investigate, in which order to initialize your classes and their attributes.

In Block, to access the Window, you have to have a reference. The reference can be passed to the ctor of Block:

```
class Block extends Rectangle {
    public int groundID;
    public int airID;
    Window window; 

    public Block (int x, int y, int width, int height, int groundID, int airID, Window window) {
        setBounds (x, y, width, height);
        this.groundID = groundID;
        this.airID = airID;
        this.window = window;
    }
    public void draw (Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage (window.tileset_ground [groundID], x, y, width, height, null);
        if (airID != Value.airAir) {
            g.drawImage (window.tileset_air [airID], x, y, width, height, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Who creates Blocks? It is Room, so Room itself needs to know about the Window (as long as you don't change your design fundamentally).

```
public Room (Window w) {
    block = new Block [worldHeight] [worldWidth];
    for (int y=0; y <block.length; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x <block [0].length; x++) {
            block [y] [x] = new Block (x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize, Value.groundGrass, Value.airAir, w);
        }
    }
}
```

A block array is created, initialized, and the Blocks are passed the Window-parameter.

In draw, you don't recreate the array over and over again, nor do you recreate the Blocks, but just redraw them:

```
public void draw (Graphics g) {
    for (int y=0; y <block.length; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x <block [0].length; x++) {
            block [y] [x].draw (g);
        }
    }
}
```

In Window, you create the Room, and pass it the window-reference:

```
public void define () {
    room = new Room (this);
    levels = new Levels ();
```

Comment: Okay i know that only Window.room.block is null but how can i fix it?

Comment: I think i need to change something in Room.java but what?

Comment: Maybe you can put the initialization of `block = ` into the ctor of Room? I wonder why you would need to create a new Block array on every invocation of 'draw'. But I'm not sure about the semantics of your code. You're not only recreating the block array, but the blocks inside too.